# Is it possible to scrape from a mobile app in real time?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I was hoping to be able to scrape data from a mobile app that generates results based on my location in real time. E.g. I want to be able to pull data on where the closest taxi to me is in real time and display it as part of a different mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible to get content from another app if that app doesn't implement it... If your device is rooted and your app has root access there will probably be a way to achieve this...

Most apps that give the users information also have a (mobile)site so it would be easier to scrape those than scraping an other app...

EDIT:
Most apps store their information in a database or someother way, you could always try to access this data (root) and interpret it in your app or sniff so you could see what webservice the app connects to and use this webservice in your app...

IMPORTANT:
MAKE SURE YOU HAVE PERMISSION OF THE PERSON WHO PROVIDES THE DATA TO USE IT IN YOUR OWN APP!

Comment: In short: no you can't without root, maybe with root. But there are other ways to achieve the same effect, but those are probably illegal...

Answer (score 0):

You could reverse engineer the network calls made by the app so you can call them yourself directly. Assuming this is for an Android app:

1. install the Chrome extension [ARC Welder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn) so that you can run Android
   apps on your computer
2. download the app's APK and load it in ARC Welder
3. interact with the app and use a tool such as Wireshark or Fiddler to monitor how the app loads the data you are after from their backend server
4. then replicate this network call to scrape the data directly in your own solution

See [this blog post](http://webscraping.com/blog/How-to-scrape-Android-Apps/) for more details, though whether you can legally reuse the data in your own app will depend on their terms of services.